# Are git submodules a good solution for storing a large DB dump?

Tags: database, git, development-environment, git-submodules

I.e., we have a 20MB bzip2 sql file of development data that we'd like to have versioned along with our development code.

However, we don't want this file pulled down from the repo by default with every fresh clone/fetch.

One solution seems to be storing this large file in a separate repo and then link to it with a submodule. Then, a developer would fetch the db file only when they need to retrieve and reset their development database. And then, when there's a schema change, the database file would be updated, committed to the external repo, and the submodule updated.

Is this a good development workflow? Or is there a better way of doing this?

EDIT: The uncompressed SQL dump is 360MB.

EDIT: Github says "no", don't do this:

> **Database dumps**
>
> Large SQL files do not play well with version control systems such as
>   Git. If you are looking to provide your developers with the most
>   recent production dataset, we recommend using Dropbox for sharing
>   files like these among your developers.

Comment: I'd say submodule yes, bzip no.  Let the repo compression do that, crank its config settings if the defaults don't get enough, but compress-first shuts off just about all of git's versioning capabilities.

Comment: @jthill Unfortunately, the file is too large for github, uncompressed: remote: error: File production-dump.sql is 362.49 MB; this exceeds GitHub's file size limit of 100 MB

Answer (score 1):

I ended up making a simple web server serve the schema dump directory from the repo where dumps are stored. The repo grew really quickly because the dumps are large, and it was slowing people down just to clone it when they had to bring up new nodes.